# Separate Toon Glossy from Toon Diffuse

Tags: cycles-render-engine, toon-shading

I'm trying to make a simple Toon material with a Diffuse and a Glossy component.
My problem is that the glossy part affects the diffuse part and makes it lighter. I would like them to be separate and not affect each other.

In the image below, I want the darker part to be all diffuse and the light part to be all glossy.

It seems it should be easy if I knew what to plug into the Fac of the mix shader. Or am I misunderstanding something and there's a better way to achieve this?

I would prefer to use cycles if possible.

[image]

Edit 1:
Trying the Add Shader:

[image]

Edit 2:
Switching to a Sun light, and reducing the Glossy component factor to 0.1 gives a decent result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use an Add Shader instead of a Mix shader node, and you will notice that the glossy component doesn't add anything to the diffuse component.

Play with lighting to get the desired result.

Comment: I actually get the opposite result with the Add Shader, i.e. the Diffuse component has no effect. I added an image showing that attempt above.

Comment: I took your advice to play with the lighting though, and got pretty close to what I wanted, see last image above.